# Unable to grant user access to directories in a share

Tags: windows, permissions, file-permissions

I am running windows 2003.  We have active directory in my organization.  I have a user -- for example -- called Bob Smith (e-mail is bsmith@organization.com, again, made up).

Just for the record, Windows permissions are somehwat voodoo for me (if you happen to include a good primer or suggest a good book I will be very happy).

I have this directory layout.
\websrv\Inetworkpublish$\www-intra\ac\dir\Finance-Dashboard

The directory "ac" I have shared by going to properties and turning it into a share.  The directory "dir" is just a directory.  I have also made "Finance-Dashboard" into a share.  I gave the above path to the user and told him to put it in Start -> Run (he has Windows 7) and he got this error:

```
Cannot find file "\\websrv\Inetworkpublish$\www-intra\ac\dir\Finance-Dashboard".  Verify the path or Internet address is correct.
```

Ok, I simply do not understand, but *why* is it not working for him?  I am genuinely lost here.

I suppose it would not hurt to give you the permissions that I gave this guy :)

```
+------------------------------+--------------+----------+----------+
|                              |      Hex     |Folder and|          |
|                              |Representation|subfolders|Files only|
+------------------------------+--------------+----------+----------+
|Full Control                  |       F      |          |          |
+------------------------------+--------------+----------+----------+
|Traverse Folder / Execute File|       6      |     x    |          |
+------------------------------+--------------+----------+----------+
|List Folder / Read Data       |       1      |     x    |     x    |
+------------------------------+--------------+----------+----------+
|Read Attributes               |       8      |     x    |     x    |
+------------------------------+--------------+----------+----------+
|Read Extended Attributes      |       4      |     x    |     x    |
+------------------------------+--------------+----------+----------+
|Create Files / Write Data     |       2      |     x    |     x    |
+------------------------------+--------------+----------+----------+
|Create Folders / Append Data  |       3      |     x    |     x    |
+------------------------------+--------------+----------+----------+
|Write Attributes              |       9      |     x    |     x    |
+------------------------------+--------------+----------+----------+
|Write Extended Attributes     |       5      |     x    |     x    |
+------------------------------+--------------+----------+----------+
|Delete Subfolders and Files   |       7      |          |          |
+------------------------------+--------------+----------+----------+
|Delete                        |       A      |     x    |     x    |
+------------------------------+--------------+----------+----------+
|Read Permissions              |       B      |     x    |     x    |
+------------------------------+--------------+----------+----------+
|Change Permissions            |       C      |          |          |
+------------------------------+--------------+----------+----------+
|Take Ownership                |       D      |          |          |
+------------------------------+--------------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Quick question you don't have anything that might deny access for that user. Because deny always overrides allow?

Comment: If it is set somewhere in a higher directory, then I have no idea since it is not inherited down in the lower directories.  I have given access to other people in the past (not directly, but so that the path can be used by an application) and they were able to access the directory.

Comment: just wanted to check for trouble shooting purposes. I figured that was not the case but if it was then it could be an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the hostname of \\websrv\ replace it with the ip like \\192.168.1.2\ worth a shot. Maybe he can't reach the server at all? Side note I just found out in windows $ is alright in the folder structure from this post. lol

Comment: The $ has something to do with indicating that this is a share.  I do not know why, but it does (not saying that you can have directories called $uper_$ecret_$tuff, you might, I do not know).  I did most of my permissions as chmod -R 0664 and the like on a Linux machine for the past 6 years, so this is very new to me :)

Comment: But I think that this is not a DNS issue, the name gets resolved correctly, he is merely getting an error message stating that he does not have access to the file.  This is not a networking issue, I have not had one before and the networking department did not get any complaints from other users.

Comment: `$` simply means a hidden share -- Windows Explorer and `net view` do not show shares ending with a `$` when browsing the network. (They are still listed at protocol level, though) This function only works for shares; if you name a *folder* `secret$` there will be *nothing* special about it.

Comment: @gp443: The message does *not* mention access; it says "path not found", which might mean an incorrect server name, share name, or path.

Answer (score 0):

Try the UNC path \websrv\Finance-Dashboard.  Any change?  Can the user access any share on that system?  Does he see anything if he uses path \webserv?

If there s a DNS issue, the suggestion from @nhutto will point that out.

Comment: I sent that string to him to try it out.  I will keep you posted if this works or not.

Answer (score 0):

SMB paths start at the shared directory, not at the filesystem root. If the computer is named `websrv` and you shared `C:\Inetworkpublish$\www-intra\ac`, the path will be `\\websrv\ac`.

```
C:\Inetworkpublish$\www-intra\ac\dir\Finance-Dashboard\
                     \\websrv\ac\dir\Finance-Dashboard\
```

If you create a second share *below* the first one, it will again start at the directory you shared, not at C:\ or anything:

```
C:\Inetworkpublish$\www-intra\ac\dir\Finance-Dashboard\
                     \\websrv\ac\dir\Finance-Dashboard\
                            \\websrv\Finance-Dashboard\
```

(The share name and the directory name are by default identical, but they do not have to be. You can always rename shares.)

---

When used as the last character of a share name, `$` makes it hidden – not displayed by Explorer or `net view`. For example, `\\server\C$` will be hidden (but `\\server\foo$bar` will remain visible). This is purely a convenience feature, though; such shares are still listed at protocol level.

The `$` character has no special meaning in file or folder names.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows XP, I  ran into such similar issue. The reason is TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper in Services.msc needs to select Startup Type of Automatic instead of Manual. It works after this setting change